Trimming video in VidCoder
I used to be able to cut different parts of a video using the VidCoder video editing program. But I have forgotten how to do so.
Does anyone know how to edit parts out of a video using VidCoder?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

This is a pretty basic question that doesn't show us any research you have done or what you have tried. Have you reviewed the documentation on this product at all? Have you searched for tutorials or guides?

I can only trim the start and end of the video by holding the mouse buttons down and sliding a bar across at the start and the end. I have edited multiple parts from the video, such as ad breaks before., but I have forgotten how to. All the Vidcoder tutorials only show how to trim a video, or have information about cropping and encoding.
